# owl how to (if possible ) annotate an owl:class

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, owl, ontology

I used to annotate a predicate like the following:

```
 <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://music.org/musicontology/mo#fromEra">
        <rs:hasSimilarityValue rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double">0.1</rs:hasSimilarityValue>
    </rdf:Description>
```

where fromEra is a predicate and has a property called hasSimilarityValue which its value is 0.1

I would like to do the same for some classes, I dont' know if that is possible in owl or not, I supposed that is possible because when looking for the owl generated from my protege i can see the followings:

```
 <!-- http://music.org/musicontology/mo#JoyfulFeeling -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="http://music.org/musicontology/mo#JoyfulFeeling">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://music.org/musicontology/mo#Feeling"/>
    </owl:Class>
```

so it sounds that it is possible to do that.

Just to make my question clear, I would like to end up with something like this:

> JoyfulFeeling is a class that has a property called hasSimilarityValue, which its range is double

Comment: Classes and properties (or predicates) are annotated the same way. Use an AnnotationProperty. This can be done in Protege or through code, if you're using an API to create your ontology.

Answer (score 2):

In general there is no problem having properties associated with a class.  If the property is of type owl:AnnotationProperty, then reasoners will ignore it, if running a reasoner is a concern at all.